# MS Access to DB2

Tags: decimal, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to inserted records from MS Access to DB2 on iseries. Everything works well except one field that is decimal. It shows as .0162 in Access. I have tried all kinds of options for how the field is defined but the field on iseries always ends up to be .01 or .01000. Any ideas how I can make this field work?

Comment: I'm not a DB2 expert, but my first guess is to ensure that DB2 uses enough decimal places (for display AND storage!). Looks like it cuts everything behind decimal place 2.

Comment: How are you getting records out of MS Access and into DB2 for i? Java? C#? How is the table defined in DB2 for i? If you post the relevant pieces of code and the definition of the table in DB2 for i I'm sure the community can help you.

Comment: How is the field defined in DB2? What does the value represent, money perhaps?

Comment: Just to add more info to this. I am using an append Query out of Access. I created a table in Access by importing an Excel spread sheet. I forced the field in question to be Number, field size = Double, Format = General Number, Decimal Places = Auto. I did try all kinds of combinations on these. I tried Field Size to be Decimal and I tried making Decimal Places to be multiple different numbers. In the Access Database I used ODBC to link in the iseries table. The problem field is defined as DECIMAL(13, 05) although I tried multiple combinations of that too. It always ends up to be .01000

Comment: So, do you have MS-Access "seeing" the DB2 table via an ODBC link? Are you doing something like INSERT INTO DB2_TABLE_NAME select * from ACCESS_TABLE_NAME ? or, are you using some other way -- e.g. a program that you've written?

Comment: Found a way of getting it up. I defined the field on iseries side as Char(08) and was able to get the amount up. The field in Access is defined as Double

Comment: Yes the query was doing an INSERT in access

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input and interest.